# What is the difference between kubeadm join and kubernetes api node creation

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I noticed that we can create node by [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/cluster-resources/node-v1/)

1. What is the difference between [Kubeadm join](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/) and this api?
2. Is it possible to create a new worker node only by Kubernetes Api (without kubeadm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Node object in Kubernetes API

You *can* create *Node objects* via Kubernetes API - these Node objects are just *representations* for nodes in the cluster, they must also exists e.g. a machine with a [Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/).

See [Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/) in the Kubernetes documentation.

### Join a machine to a cluster with kubeadm join

`kubeadm join` is a tool and command to join a machine to the cluster as a node. This includes [many steps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/#join-workflow) including bootstrapping the node using cryptographic certiticates.

Comment: So `kubeadm join` and create Node objects via Kubernetes API do the same things?

Comment: @Justin it is very different things, I updated my answer. `kubeadm join` is a tool and command to join a machine to the cluster.